# primefaces jsf hibernate - in validation phase : failed to lazily initialize a collection

Tags: hibernate, validation, jsf, session, primefaces

I'm struggling on a problem which happen in the JSF validation phase, somehow that validation is doing something that hibernates doesn't like (failed to lazily initialize a collection, no session or session was closed) and I'd like to understand what.

The context is this one : I have a check, which is linked to a CheckType in a many to many relationship. I'm in the process of editing an existing check (in that edit page many comboboxes are offered in order to allow me to link it to a particular checktype).

I'm also using Primefaces.

The problem happens at the end of the validation process, but my converter works fine (returns the right result).

Moreover, what I don't really get is why there is a lazily, while all these objects are loaded in EAGER mode.

Thanks for your insight, I'm quiet new to hibernate and linking it to JSF also :/

### Stacktrace

```
11:15:08,137 INFO  [com.bdls.ids.utils.BDPhaseListener] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) Before PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3
11:15:11,439 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) Hibernate: 
11:15:11,440 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3)     select

11:15:11,486 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) Hibernate: 
11:15:11,486 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3)     select

11:15:11,503 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) Hibernate: 
11:15:11,504 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3)     select


11:15:12,942 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) Hibernate: 
11:15:12,944 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3)     select

11:15:13,023 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) Hibernate: 
11:15:13,023 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3)     select

11:15:13,040 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) Hibernate: 

11:15:13,062 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) Hibernate: 


11:15:13,856 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) failed to lazily initialize a collection, no session or session was closed: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection, no session or session was closed
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:393) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:385) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:378) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.add(PersistentSet.java:206) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.convertSelectManyValuesForModel(MenuRenderer.java:382) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.convertSelectManyValue(MenuRenderer.java:129) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.getConvertedValue(MenuRenderer.java:315) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.component.selectmanycheckbox.SelectManyCheckboxRenderer.getConvertedValue(SelectManyCheckboxRenderer.java:36) [primefaces-3.4.2.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1030) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:960) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1233) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:698) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1172) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79) [primefaces-3.4.2.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at com.bdls.ids.controller.login.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:39) [classes:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at com.bdls.ids.controller.login.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:48) [classes:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_32]

11:15:13,901 INFO  [com.bdls.ids.utils.BDPhaseListener] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) After PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3
```

I've only put the interesting parts for brevety :

### Xhtml

```
<h:form id="new-items" prependId="false">
    <label for="typechecks">Type of checks :</label>
    <p:selectManyCheckbox id="typechecks" value="#{checksController.itemEdited.checkTypes}" layout="pageDirection" converter="checkTypeConverter">
        <f:selectItems value="#{checkTypeController.allItems}" var="checkType" itemLabel="#{checkType.name}" />
    </p:selectManyCheckbox>
<p:commandButton id="save" value="Save" action="#{checksController.persistItemEdited}" styleClass="btnFooterFormNewItems" icon="ui-icon-check" update="new-items" />

</h:form>
```

### Converter

```
@FacesConverter("checkTypeConverter")
public class CheckTypeConverter implements Converter {

    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (value == null || value.toString().isEmpty()) {
            return ""; 
        }
        return ((UnversionedObject) value).getId().toString();
    }

    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent arg1, String value) {

        CheckTypeService checkTypeService = FacesContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(context).getBean("checkTypeService",
                CheckTypeService.class);
        return checkTypeService.getById(Integer.parseInt(value));
    }
}
```

### Controller

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ChecksController implements Serializable {
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ChecksController.class);

    // -------------------------------------------------
    // properties
    // -------------------------------------------------
    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{checksService}")
    private ChecksService checksService;

    // -------------------------------------------------
    // parameters
    // -------------------------------------------------
    private List<Check> allChecks;
    private Check[] selectedItem;
    private Check itemEdited = new Check();

    // -------------------------------------------------
    // constructor
    // -------------------------------------------------
    public ChecksController() {
        log.info("Creation of checks controller");

        allChecks = new ArrayList<Check>();

    }

    // -------------------------------------------------
    // methods
    // -------------------------------------------------
    @PostConstruct
    private void load() {
        if(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostback()) return;

        log.info("loading list of checks...");

        allChecks = checksService.getAll();
        log.info(String.format("Loaded %s items", allChecks.size()));
    }

    public void delete(Check c)
    {
        try{
            checksService.delete(c);
        }catch(Exception e){
            log.error("Error when deleting object "+c);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void prefillFrom(String modelID) {
        log.info("Pre-filling based on model " + modelID);

        if (modelID == null) // new item
            return;

        // in this case, the item must exist (edition)
        itemEdited = checksService.getById(Integer.parseInt(modelID));
        if (itemEdited == null) {
            UINotification.sendAsError("Item does not exist", String.format("The item %s does not exist", modelID));
            log.error(String.format("The item %s does not exist", modelID));
        }
    }

    public void persistItemEdited(){
        log.info("persisting item edited...");

//      CheckType c = new CheckType();
//      c.setName("jolitest");
//      
//      itemEdited.getCheckTypes().add(c);
//      c.getChecks().add(itemEdited);
//      
        try{
            checksService.saveOrUpdate(itemEdited);
        }catch(Exception e){
            log.error("Error when saving object "+itemEdited);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        itemEdited = new Check() ;
    }

    public void test()
    {
        CheckType ct = new CheckType();
        ct.setName("toto");

        itemEdited.getCheckTypes().add(ct);


        Set<CheckType> set = new HashSet<CheckType>();
        set.add(ct);
        itemEdited.setCheckTypes(set);
    }

    getters and setters...
```

### Service

```
@Service("checksService")
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class ChecksServiceImpl implements ChecksService {
    @Autowired
    CheckDAO checkDAO;

    @Autowired
    CheckTypeDAO checkTypeDAO;

    /**
     * retrieves a UnversionedObject based on its id
     */
    public Check getById(Integer id) {
        return checkDAO.getById(id);
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public Check saveOrUpdate(Check c) {
        //for many-to-many relations, re-attach the entities
        if (c.getCheckTypes() != null && c.getCheckTypes().size() > 0)
        {
            List<CheckType> checkTypes = new ArrayList<CheckType>(c.getCheckTypes().size());
            for (CheckType ct : c.getCheckTypes()) {
                checkTypes.add(checkTypeDAO.getById(ct.getId()));
            }
            c.getCheckTypes().clear();
            c.getCheckTypes().addAll(checkTypes);
        }

        return checkDAO.saveOrUpdateDetached(c);
    }

    /**
     * returns a list of all checks
     */
    @Override
    public List<Check> getAll() {
        List<Check> list = checkDAO.getAll();
        return list;
    }

    /**
     * empty the extra relations and deletes the object
     */
    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public void delete(Check c) {
        // attach object
        c = checkDAO.getById(c.getId());

        // initialize list
        Hibernate.initialize(c.getCheckTypes());

        // first remove relations to checktype
        c.getCheckTypes().clear();

        // update
        checkDAO.saveOrUpdateDetached(c);

        // now delete
        checkDAO.delete(c);
    }

}
```

### DAO (impl)

```
@Repository
public class CheckDAOImpl extends BaseDAOimpl<Check> implements CheckDAO {

}

public abstract class BaseDAOimpl<T extends UnversionedObject> implements BaseDAO<T> {
    @Override
    public T saveOrUpdateDetached(T object) throws DataModelConsistencyException {
        updateUserAndTime(object);

        if (object.getId() != null) {
            return _entityManager.merge(object);
        } else {
            _entityManager.persist(object);
            return object;
        }
    }

rest omitted
}
```

### Check

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "IDS_SV_CHECK")
public class Check extends UnversionedObject {
    public static enum Severity {
        HIGH, MEDIUM, LOW, INFORMATIVE
    };

    @Column(length = 32)
    private String checkName;

    @Column
    private Integer subCheckID;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Severity severity;

    @Column(length = 32)
    private String description;

    @Column(length = 32)
    private String errorMsg;

    @Column(length = 32)
    private String DMVersion;

    @Column(length = 32)
    private String therapeuticArea;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "IDS_SV_CHECK_HAS_TYPE",
                joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="check_id")},
                inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="checktype_id")})
    @BatchSize(size = 100)
    private Set<CheckType> checkTypes = new HashSet<CheckType>();
        ...
```

### Checktype

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "IDS_SV_CHECKTYPE")
public class CheckType extends UnversionedObject {

    @Column(length=60)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="checkTypes",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Check> checks = new HashSet<Check>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never ever return the entity with active hibernate proxy out of transactional scope. It simply can't work. Hibernate is creating proxies for collections, that are bound to hibernate session, which is bound to transaction, which no longer exist.

Possible solutions:

1) Always detach objects from hibernate session before returing them

2) More radical, always return the copy of the object, made for example with dozer, to remove all possible proxies you could not be aware of.

3) Even more radical, and making your code more clean and understandable: never use @OneToMany or @ManyToMany annotations, if you need to operate on 1 to n or n to n relationsshipps, provide DAO for such operations, and make always explicite read, insert, update and delete. IMHO the best solution, in theory requiring more approach, in praxis requiring less approach to fight with such errors as yours.

Answer (score 3):

It is very late to reply, though I think it's best to leave track here of one more solution.

I faced the very same problem, and surfing the web I stumble upon this:

http://zenidas.wordpress.com/recipes/avoiding-lazyinitializationexception-on-jsf-selectmanymenu/

Tried this solution for my entity with a ManyToMany property and it works like a charm.

Stefano

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the backing bean lifecycle is not tied to Spring. You can have ways to do that but below is a cleaner approach.

First, make sure you have listeners in your deployment descriptors for Spring Boot Strap

### web.xml

```
<!-- Spring Bootstrap -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        a.package
        another.package
        some.other.package
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Now have a helper method for the backing beans (better in a base class) to access the context.

```
protected WebApplicationContext getContext()
{
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest());
    return WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(request.getSession().getServletContext());
}
```

Now in the backing bean access the spring bean instance by:

```
ChecksService bean = getContext().getBean(ChecksService.class);
```

That's - you should be good to go.

Comment: Another way is to get the backing bean life cycle integrated with Spring by configuring Springs custom ELResolver in `faces-config.xml`  Then all JSF managed beans will also be Spring beans and thus can have other Spring components and services autowired to them.